# Prove that $J_n J^{'}_{-n}-J_{-n}J{'}_n= -\frac{2 \sin(n\pi)}{\pi x}$

Tags: bessel-functions

Prove that

> $$J_n J^{'}_{-n}-J_{-n}J{'}_n= -\frac{2 \sin(n\pi)}{\pi x}$$

I tried by substituting value of $J^{'}_n$ but it doesn't help me out. I am unable to think how to get $\sin()$ on RHS.

I also tried to substitute series form of Bessel's function but that does not lead me anywhere. Moreover I think there is some trick to solve this.
($J_n$ is Bessel function)

When $n$ is an integer, it will be true as both LHS and RHS will turn out to be zero by using $\left(J_{-n}(x)= (-1)^nJ_n(x)\right)$, so I am left with the case when $n$ is not an integer.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? The $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and the relation follows from 
$J_{-n}=(-1)^n J_n$

Comment: @gammatester, thanks, I was typing that too. I was wondering for the case when $n$ is non integer.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the notation $J_{\nu}(z)$ for the general case and derive your equation from the Wronskian (https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.5.E1)
$$J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right)J_{-\nu}\left(z\right) + J_{\nu}\left(z\right)J_{-\nu-1}\left(z\right) = -\frac{2\sin\left(\nu\pi\right)}{\pi z}$$
and the recurrence relations (https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E2)
$$J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right) = (\nu/z)J_{\nu}\left(z\right)-J_{\nu}'\left(z\right),$$

$$J_{\mu-1}\left(z\right) = J_{\mu}'\left(z\right) +(\mu/z) J_{\mu}\left(z\right), $$

substituting $\mu = -\nu$ in the last equation gives
$$J_{-\nu-1}\left(z\right) = J_{-\nu}'\left(z\right) -(\nu/z) J_{-\nu}\left(z\right).$$
It follows, that
$$J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right)J_{-\nu}\left(z\right) =
\left((\nu/z)J_{\nu}\left(z\right)-J_{\nu}'\left(z\right)\right) J_{-\nu}\left(z\right)$$
and
$$J_{-\nu-1}\left(z\right)J_{\nu}\left(z\right) = \left(J_{-\nu}'\left(z\right) -(\nu/z) J_{-\nu}\left(z\right)\right)J_{\nu}\left(z\right)$$
Adding both equations and canceling like terms on the RHS gives
$$
J_{-\nu}'\left(z\right)J_{\nu}\left(z\right) -
J_{\nu}'\left(z\right)J_{-\nu}\left(z\right)
 = J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right)J_{-\nu}\left(z\right) + J_{-\nu-1}\left(z\right)J_{\nu}\left(z\right)$$
Now use the Wronskian and get

> $$J_{\nu}\left(z\right)J_{-\nu}'\left(z\right) -
> J_{-\nu}\left(z\right)J_{\nu}'\left(z\right) = 
> -\frac{2\sin\left(\nu\pi\right)}{\pi z}$$

Comment: can you add a more direct link for the lemmas? I couldn't find the full formal proof that was required for the given conclusion.